# How to call a static function on an ActionScript object's ancestor class?

Tags: actionscript-3, reflection, actionscript, static

The Ancestor class does, indeed, have a function called (for the sake of example) "foo".

```
public static function callAncestorStaticMethod() : void
{
    var ancestorClassName : String = getQualifiedSuperclassName(Descendant);
    var ancestorClass : Class = Class(getDefinitionByName(ancestorClassName));

    ancestorClass.foo();   //  <---- runtime error here: foo is not a function
}
```

Examining ancestorClass finds it an Object with no visible properties (ancestorClass.prototype does not either).

So, how do I call a static function on a class when I only have its name as a string at runtime ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to call a static function in the superclass using the following code:

```
var c:ChildClass = new ChildClass();
var s:String = getQualifiedSuperclassName(c);
var cl:Class = getDefinitionByName(s) as Class;

cl.foo.call();  
//cl["foo"].call();
```

A Class object has all of the static properties and methods of the Class, so this should be reliable. `cl.foo` returns a Function object that you can then `.call()`.

Comment: the secret handshake was .call()

Answer (score 1):

You can get a reference to the instance's own class using the `constructor` property, but to access the ancestor classes, you have to use `describeType` and `getDefinitionByName`.  These are powerful, but costly - so make sure you don't overuse this:

```
function callStaticAncestorProperty( instance:Object, staticProperty:String ):* {
    var type:XML = describeType( instance );
    var ret:* = instance.constructor[staticProperty];
    for each(var extend:XML in type.extendsClass) 
        ret = ret ? ret : getStaticPropertyOrUndefined( extend, staticProperty );  
    return ret;
}

function getStaticPropertyOrUndefined( extend:XML, staticProperty:String ):* {
    var clazz:Class = getDefinitionByName( extend.@type.toString().replace( "::", "." ) ) as Class;
    return clazz[staticProperty] ? clazz[staticProperty] : undefined;
}
```

This checks if the class itself has the property, and then iterates over each super type.  Note that the first value to be found will be returned, i.e. if both the subclass and a super class have this property, that of the subclass will be returned.

*Edit*

I only just realized you were asking about method calls, not properties.  That works pretty much the same way:

```
function callStaticAncestorMethod( instance:Object, staticMethod:String ):void {
    var type:XML = describeType( instance );
    var method:Function = instance.constructor[staticMethod];
    for each(var extend:XML in type.extendsClass) 
        method = method ? method : getStaticMethodOrUndefined( extend, staticMethod );  
    if (method) method();
}

function getStaticMethodOrUndefined( extend:XML, staticMethod:String ):Function {
    var clazz:Class = getDefinitionByName( extend.@type.toString().replace( "::", "." ) ) as Class;
    return clazz[staticMethod] ? clazz[staticMethod] : undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or (Based on Sam DeHaan answer's):

If Superclass and Descendant have both a String id property...

```
(getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedSuperclassName(Descendant))as Class).foo();
trace((getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedSuperclassName(Descendant))as Class).id);
```

Where :

```
// trace (Descendant.id);
// if private : compile time Error.
// 1178: Attempted access of inaccessible property id through a reference with static type Class.
var d:Descendant;
trace((getDefinitionByName("Descendant") as Class).id);
// output undefined if private : the value if public. But don't throw compile time Error.
(getDefinitionByName("Descendant") as Class).foo();
// Call static foo() from Descendant. // Throw a compile time Error if method is private

// trace (Superclass.id);
// if private : compile time Error.
// 1178: Attempted access of inaccessible property id through a reference with static type Class.
var s:Superclass;
trace((getDefinitionByName("Superclass") as Class).id);
// output undefined if private : the value if public. But don't throw compile time Error.
(getDefinitionByName("Superclass") as Class).foo();
// Call static foo() from Superclass. // Throw a compile time Error if method is private
```